# Visual Studio not reflecting changes in saved and compiled C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Saved and compiled C code in Visual Studio Code but the output is still based on previous code I had written although I doubled checked that I saved the file.

Tried looking up the build path but still confused. I saved and compiled two print statements but none of those were printed out even tho I saved and recompiled the code.

Comment: Are you certain you don't have any compile errors? Do you have multiple files and perhaps forgot to save one of them?

Comment: There is a mistake either in your code or in the way you are building it.  You will have to add the relevant files to your post if you want help.

Comment: Close all open files and check the folder you opened in the workspace is really the folder you intent to open. Open .vscode/tasks.json and check which files are being passed to the compiler (do you have any hard-coded paths?). Also try manually removing all object file then building and checking where the new objects were created.